# Trigger a Client function with a service worker

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have a chat platform I'm building for fun.  I have built notifications into the platform.   On a browser it looks like this when you click the notification, with noticeSource  being the user the new message is from.  So it knows, to focus the page and then use the `loadChat()` function to load the chat associated with that user.

```
note.onclick=function(){
                        parent.focus();
                        console.log(this);
                        loadChat(noticeSource,el);
                        this.close()
                    };
```

However, I am also running this as PWA for android, so when it detects its on a phone it uses the Service worker `showNotification` method.  I use this function to detect the click and to bring the app into focus.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event)
{
    console.log("EVENT!",event.notification.data);
    var target=event.notification.data;
    const rootUrl = new URL('./index.php', location).href;
    event.notification.close();
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll().then(matchedClients => {
            for (let client of matchedClients){
                console.log(client.url,rootUrl);
                if (client.url.indexOf(rootUrl) >= 0){
                    console.log("Focus1");
                    return client.focus();
                }
            }
            return clients.openWindow(rootUrl).then(
                function (client) {
                    console.log("Focus2");
                    client.focus();
                }
            );
        })
    );
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to communicate between the SW and the client that the client should run the `loadChat()` function and pass along the user it should run it for.  In general if someone could point me toward a resource that explains how to communicate between the SW and the client that would be appreciated.  I've looked but haven't found anything and I am assuming it's because I'm not really clear on how service workers are suppose to work.

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, I found an answer after I posted the question.  The `client` object has a method `postMessage()`, so once I have my client found I can use that to post a message with the userName,  on the client side I can use eventListener `navigator.serviceWorker.onmessage` to catch messages from the sw and execute functions.

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event)
{
    console.log("EVENT!",event.notification.data);
    var target=event.notification.data;
    const rootUrl = new URL('./index.php', location).href;
    event.notification.close();
    console.log(clients);
    event.waitUntil(
        clients.matchAll().then(matchedClients => {
            for (let client of matchedClients){
                console.log(client.url,rootUrl);
                if (client.url.indexOf(rootUrl) >= 0){
                    console.log(client);
                    client.focus();
                    client.postMessage(event.notification.data);
                    return ;
                }
            }
            return clients.openWindow(rootUrl).then(
                function (client) {
                    console.log("Focus2");
                    client.focus();
                }
            );
        })
    );
});
```

and on the client side

```
sw=navigator.serviceWorker;
sw.register('sw.js').then(function(registration){console.log("Scope:",registration.scope)});

sw.onmessage=function(event){
    loadChat(event.data,document.getElementById(event.data));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it perfectly solved the issue I was having.  I always like it when people report back to their own questions when they found an answer.  I always try to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

#### To share functions

```js
import { share } from 'sw-shared-functions';

export class HelloService {
  sayHello(name: string): string {
    return `Hello, ${name}`;
  }
}

share(new HelloService());
```

#### To load functions

```js
import { load } from 'sw-shared-functions';
import type { HelloService } from '../services/hello.service';

const helloServ = await load<HelloService>();
console.log(await helloServ.sayHello('World!'));
```